# Converting to non-scalar type

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have 2 structs of the same size, layout and alignment, but of different types. I would like to copy one onto the other.

```
struct one s1;
struct two s2;

...

s1 = (struct one)s2;  // error: conversion to non-scalar type requested
s1 = *((struct one*)&s2);  // fine?
```

Is the 2nd method safe & portable?

Bonus: What was the thinking of the language designers here, are they making sure I take off the safety before I shoot myself in the foot?

Comment: If you have two struct types with the same size and layout, and you want to be able to assign values from one to the other, why are they different types in the first place?

Comment: @KeithThompson: Agreed, that sounds like an XY-problem.

Comment: "What was the thinking of the language designers here, are they making sure I take off the safety before I shoot myself in the foot?" - You confuse cause and effect. You shoot yourself in the foot by having two identical (as you state - we don't know for sure) but seperately declared `struct`s. Now you ask how to shoot your leg not to feel the pain from your foot.

Comment: Btw. at least there might be ways in C to mess with this. Strongly typed languages would just show you the finger.

Comment: @Olaf: Who said that it is the OP who's "having two identical but seperately declared `struct`s"? Situations like that often naturally arise when the two `struct` types originate from two different modules, neither of which is controlled y the OP. Of course, in that case the similarity of the `struct`'s layout is purely coincidental and should not be relied upon. But still in such cases it is not in the OP's power to replace these two types with one.

Comment: @AnT: In this case you cannot rely on them having the same layout, but should copy field-wise. Leave optimisations to the compiler.

Comment: @AnT A reasonable scenario, but given two `struct` from differing modules, today they may have same size/alignment, etc., but change due to future maintenance and developments.  Defensive coding would avoid taking too much advantage of the present day similarity

Comment: @jayjay You accepted an incorrect answer. The behavior of the second method is undefined, see the other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39988485/4082723

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second method is undefined behaviour due to violating the strict aliasing rule. Even though `struct one` and `struct two` have the same layout, it is not permitted to use an lvalue of type `struct one` to access an object of type `struct two` or vice versa.

In general, accessing an object via an expression of a different type is only allowed for using a character type to access another object; or via a union.

An alternative would be:

```
memcpy(&s1, &s2, sizeof s1);
```